# how to display checkbox inside richtextbox for acceptance of Terms and Conditions

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on window application. I have a form where I will be displaying terms and conditions against shopping done. Below Terms and Conditions, I want to show Checkbox which user have to check as an acceptance before proceeding.

This Checkbox should come below the terms and conditions. If terms and conditions are long enough then user have to scroll down to make sure he has gone through all the agreement. Only after which he can check.

I was thinking to do it with rich textbox. Is it possible to do with any way.

Comment: @Bolu: Actually, It could be a way to get out, but real problem still persists as my control may have less content due to which there may be no need to scroll in that case checkbox will be shown on bottom. But is should have been immediate to the ending of content

Comment: Based on your question: "This Checkbox should come below the terms and conditions. If terms and conditions are long enough then user have to scroll down to make sure he has gone through all the agreement. Only after which he can check." Now as you comment above "my control may have less content due to which there may be no need to scroll in that case checkbox will be shown on bottom" I can't see any problem with that, so you need to decide what do you really want to achieve. Do you want to add "blank" into the content to make the scrollbar showing?

Comment: @Bolu: No, I dont want to add any space between the text for Scroll Bar to appear, just at the end of terms and conditions checkbox should become visible. But I think i need to play with its position and all these things

Comment: Yes, in the case you want the checkbox follow the richTextbox's content without a gap, just set the checkBox.Dock=DockStyle.None then checkbox's Y position based on richTextbox.Height+richTextbox.Location.Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scrollbar events to determine when user scrolled whole text and then set checkbox visible. In that case checkbox can be initialy posiotioned outside rich text box ( ex. below).

Comment: +1 for the idea. But maybe it would be better not to show/hide, but to enable/disable the checkbox according to the scroll events.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't**.

- Concerning *new users*, the checkbox will stay unnoticed by most users, and things will be really confusing when the user will, on submit, see the message saying she didn't check the checkbox, but there will be no visible checkbox in the form. Since there are no existing forms which use such thing, few people will be able to guess it, so some users will just abandon the process, and other will go submit a bug, telling you that the checkbox is missing.
- Concerning *old users*, they don't and won't need to read Terms and Conditions every time, so putting the checkbox at the end creates excise, but brings nothing at all to compensate it.

**But you can**. Now, technically, you can use a scrollbar, then put in the scrollable area a richedit (with no inner scroll) and a checkbox below. I don't think there is a way to put the checkbox inside the richedit.

Answer (score 0):

use a panel to hold the richTextbox and the checkbox. 
set

```
Panel.AutoSize=false; 
Panel.AutoScroll=true;

richTextbox.Dock=DockStyle.Top;
richTextbox.ScrollBars=RichTextBoxScrollBars.None;
richTextbox.Height=richTextbox.lines.length*20; 

checkBox.Dock=DockStyle.Bottom;
```

**EDIT**

To make checkBox always follows the richTextbox, add following code after:

```
checkBox.Dock=DockStyle.None;
checkBox.Location=new Point(checkBox.Location.X, richTextbox.Height+richText.box.Location.Y);
```