# controls inside richtextbox down or up with scroller

Tags: c#, winforms

Inside my `richtextbox` have a `checkbox`, when scroll down or up my richtextbox, checkbox not scrolling whit it.

```
CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
chk.Name = "Chk" + i;
chk.Location = new Point(80,10+i);
chk.Text = "Save";
chk.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 100);
richTextBox1.Controls.Add(chk);
i++;
```

Can you tell me how to solve it.

Comment: Could you share your code as well!!

Comment: A RichTextBox cannot contain a CheckBox object. Explain what your code should do.

Comment: ...
CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
chk.Name = "Chk" + i;
chk.Location = new Point(80,10+i);
chk.Text = "Save";
chk.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 100);
richTextBox1.Controls.Add(chk);
i++;

Comment: Edit your question with this code as you can see comments look ugly and this is not the place for the source codes

Comment: @Mohsen Put the code in the question

Comment: First of all why would you need a checkbox inside richtextbox? Can't it be outside?

Comment: Its better to use Containers like Panel,etc to hold child controls. Can you explain why you want the check boxes inside a rich text box?

Comment: i show multiline text in richtextbox after each topic set a checkbox for user to save that topic in file in your hard drive.

Answer (score 2):

A `RichTextBox` cannot contain a `CheckBox` object. and you have set static point for location of your checkpoint

```
chk.Location = new Point(80,10+i)
```

, and it is over `RichTextBox` ,  not into that

Comment: `richTextBox1.Controls.Add(chk);` adds it into `richtextbox` only. Not as `RTF` format but as control. What's your point

Comment: i don't create checkbox in different location, i need when scroll of richtextbox down or up checkbox in it too.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the `MouseWheel` and `Scroll` events of your `RichTextBox` and use the `GetScrollPos` win32 function to get the new position of the scrollbar of your `RichTextBox`, then update the position of your `CheckBox` accordingly. Notice that when the `MouseWheel` is raised, the position of the ScrollBar is not changed to the new one immediately, it will be changed smoothly from the current to the new one. That's why we have to use a `Timer` to call the `GetScrollPos` repeatedly an periodically until the return position is the same. The effect we get is not perfect as the smoothness of the scrollbar moving but it's close to that smoothness and far better than calling the `GetScrollPos` once right in the `MouseWheel` event handler.

However in this code, I would like to use `NativeWindow` to hook into the message loop and fetch the messages sent to the `RichTextBox`, here is the code which works OK, this code is just a demo and handle the `Vertical scrolling` only. You can find more info on `WM_HSCROLL` and `GetScrollPos` to handle the `Horizontal scrolling` (it's easy because it's very much similar to the `Vertical scrolling`):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern int GetScrollPos(IntPtr hwnd, int nBar);
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        chk.Text = ".NET pro";
        chk.Parent = richTextBox1;
        chk.Top = 100;//Notice the initial Top to update the position properly later.            
        nativeRichText.AssignHandle(richTextBox1.Handle);
        //Scroll event handler for the nativeRichText
        nativeRichText.Scroll += (s, e) =>
        {
            chk.Top = 100-e.Y;
        };
        //TextChanged event handler for the richTextBox1
        richTextBox1.TextChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            chk.Top = 100-GetScrollPos(richTextBox1.Handle, 1);
        };            
    }
    CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
    NativeRichTextBox nativeRichText = new NativeRichTextBox();        
    public class NativeRichTextBox : NativeWindow
    {
        Timer t = new Timer();
        int y = -1;
        public NativeRichTextBox()
        {
            t.Interval = 30;
            t.Tick += (s, e) =>
            {                                     
                int y2 = Form1.GetScrollPos(Handle, 1);//nBar =1 => Vertical bar
                if (y2 == y) { t.Stop(); return; }
                y = y2;
                if (Scroll != null) Scroll(this, new ScrollEventArgs(0, y));                    
            };
        }
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == 0x115)//WM_VSCROLL = 0x115
            {
                int wp = m.WParam.ToInt32();
                int low = wp & 0x00ff;
                if (low == 4 || low == 5)//SB_THUMBPOSITION = 4   SB_THUMBTRACK = 5
                {
                    if (Scroll != null) Scroll(this, new ScrollEventArgs(0, wp >> 16));
                }
                else t.Start();
            }
            if (m.Msg == 0x20a)//WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x20a
            {
                y = -1;
                t.Start();
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);                
        }
        public class ScrollEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public int X { get; set; }
            public int Y { get; set; }
            public ScrollEventArgs(int x, int y)
            {
                X = x;
                Y = y;
            }
        }
        public delegate void ScrollEventHandler(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e);
        public event ScrollEventHandler Scroll;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have seen around checkboxes inside comboboxes or dropdown lists.
It is possible to do it. You may try with third parties controls like [this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/checkboxes/defaultcs.aspx), or code your own. This topic was already discussed in another question on SO, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013920/how-to-display-checkbox-inside-richtextbox-for-acceptance-of-terms-and-condition), so we do not restart debating the  same topic in this question.

What you are obtaining with your code instead, is just to put graphically one control on  another but they do not interact to each other. They are two separate controls.