# add a checked list to a RichTextbox Control in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I'd like to insert the rtf code for a checkbox field in the position where the cursor is within the control but I'm having some problems figuring out how to determine where this position is located within the control's rtf text. Is this possible?

[image: Something like this]

Comment: RTBs are __really__ bad at inserting __anything__ into the Text. If you mean you want to nest a checkox on the RTB control: Simple but most likely not at all what you really want. Where is the image you show us from??

Comment: Is it enough to insert a check-box character/icon?

Comment: Check this out and this seems similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013920/how-to-display-checkbox-inside-richtextbox-for-acceptance-of-terms-and-condition

Comment: @TaW I'd prefer to make it an rtf solution, so the text can be exported and used on any software that can read this format (say Wordpad).  This is a screenshot from a pet project.

Comment: @RezaAghaei no, the checkbox has to be interactive.

Comment: @AT-2016 I saw that post but not really the way I want to go with this.

Comment: I'm really not sure you can do this. The only possible course of action I see would be: Analyse a working example, maybe using MSWord and insert the raw Rtf code it generated for the field.  The last time I tried something like this it failed completely :-(  RTB is really a very __lightweight RTF__ control. - Did you succeed displaying and using such a externally created CheckBox field in a RTB??

Comment: @TaW that's exactly what I'm trying to accomplish but no luck yet.

Comment: Actually I just tried to save a word document with a checkbox as rtf but word confirmed: rtf simply doesn't support it. so: it just can't be done.

Comment: @TaW I was afraid of that. The specifications for rtf 1.5 say it's supported though.

Comment: Probably if you share your actual requirement, more effective helps can be provided. You also can consider using an html editor. Having a `CheckBox` in a html text is normal. But in general I can't imagine what would be the usage of having such interactive check-boxes in a rich text. I've never seen check boxes in rich texts. If you need to create a content management system you need to re-think about the tool you are using and the product you want to create.

Comment: Well, he wants live fields; these are quite normal in a PDF and clearly also in a Word document.. But a RTB is not so much a small Word than a better TextBox

Comment: @RezaAghaei My project is just trying to emulate a note taking app (like Evernote).  The check boxes are needed because the user can create a to-do list and then mark each item as done (this functionality is present in many to-do and note taking apps).  I've been considering ditching RTB and using an html WYSIWYG control but I'm still considering my options and since this is just a learning project for me, I'd like to create it myself instead of just downloading something from the web.

Comment: @EnmanuelG So it seems using a `DataGridView` is enough. You can simply create a DataGridView which have 2 columns, a check box column and a text box column. Then add user to add rows. Also after user checked a checkbox, just set the font style to `Strikeout` or make it red or some other customization. You can hide row headers and column headers and some other customization.

Comment: Let me know if you are interested in such example :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei thanks for the offer but not really the way I want to handle it.

Comment: No problem :) If I were you probably I used `DataGridView` for such functionality, and forgot rich text format. But you know your requirement better :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `RichTextBox.CaretPosition` is what you need. It gives you a `TextPointer` value (`System.Windows.Documents.TextPointer`).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.caretposition(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The question is for Winforms. There the caret is always at SelectionStart.